# Kendo Grid groupping

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I read [this topic](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/can-t-drag-column-headers-to-group-by.aspx) and use open source edition of kendo web, my current version is Kendo UI Web v2012.3.1114. My problem is exist as the link above and I could not solve it.

Part of my script is here:

```
function load() {                
            var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

            if (grid) {
                //destroy the previous Grid instance
                grid.destroy();
                //clean up the html
                grid.wrapper.html("");
            }
            var crudServiceBaseUrl = "WebForm.aspx",
                //datasource = null;
                dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "?q=load&sql=" + $("#tbSQL").val(),
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    update: {
                        url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "?q=update&sql=" + $("#tbSQL").val(),
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    destroy: {
                        url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "?q=destroy&sql=" + $("#tbSQL").val(),
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    create: {
                        url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "?q=create&sql=" + $("#tbSQL").val(),
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                            return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                        }
                    }
                },
                batch: true,
                pageSize: 20,
                schema: getmodel()
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                navigatable: true,
                //pageable: true,
                selectable: true,
                //groupable: true,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: {
                    refresh: true,
                    pageSizes: true
                },
                height: 500,
                toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
                columns: getColumns(),
                editable: true
            });
        }
```

Every thing is ok, but only after loading page I can only One time group by headers.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this behavior is improved in the latest version of KendoUI 2012 Q3 SP1 (v.2012.3.1315), where the grouping is working as expected. For convenience I created this [sample](http://tinyurl.com/a3ay5qk).

Comment: Greate Help Vladimir ! Thanks alot

Comment: You Can Download This Realese from http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/js/kendo.web.min.js